Error: void value not ignored as it ought to be done = radio.read(&Irms, sizeof(float));
Good morning everyone, I had this sketch that worked now when loading the program gives me an error:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

float Irms ;
RF24 radio(9, 10);
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;

void setup(void) {

  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe);
  radio.startListening();
  Serial.println("setup() - Inizializzazione completata");
  delay(300);
}

void loop(void) {
  if ( radio.available() )
  {
    bool done = false;
    
    while (!done)
      delay(1000);

    {
      delay(1000);
      done = radio.read(&Irms, sizeof(float));


BTW, be careful as while loop is infinite (there is only delay(1000) and done never changes)

This statement:
done = radio.read(&Irms, sizeof(float));
is not compatible with the current <RF24.h> library.
The read() method now has this signature:
void read (void *buf, uint8_t len)
You can either adapt your code or use the ancient "maniacbug" library https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24
which has the following signature for read():
bool read( void* buf, uint8_t len );

Can you help me modify my code? Thanks

@ksalva Your code in the question appears to be truncated. Show your entire code and I will attempt to suggest a fix and add it into the answer.
